# How to subset a column from one file to the same column in another file?

Tags: r, date, time, multiple-columns, subset

I have two different .csv files. One of the files, let's call it CA, has a set of dates and times in one column (structured as: `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`). I have another .csv file, let's call is CA_adjusted, that has a column structured in the same manner.

I want to subset CA_adjusted with the dates and times of CA, so that I can pull out all relevant data in CA_adjusted. I would, preferably, like to subset that Date and Time column itself from CA to the Date and Time column in CA_adjusted. How do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `read.csv` and `merge`, particularly the `all.x` and `all.y` arguments in `merge`.

Comment: so both just have one column? try reading them in: `CA <- read.csv('~/desktop/CA.csv', header = FALSE, colClasses = 'POSIXct')` and edit your question with the results

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I'm not 100% clear what type of join you need, because these things are hard to describe! But, I think a `semi_join` will do what you want. It will return the table you specify with matching cases in another table. An example:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
require("dplyr")

set.seed(0)
x <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)
x <- data.frame(x)
y <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)
y <- data.frame(y)
y$x <- y$y         # so dplyr knows which columns to join on
which(x$x == y$y)

a <- semi_join(x, y)  # returns table x with matching rows in y
```

Check out the other `join` options in dplyr if this isn't exactly what you want:

```
?dplyr::join
```